# chartjs: bars smaller than actual column, tooltip doesn't display

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

[image]

As you can see my bars are not covering the entire width of the label 'column'.
My tooltip only shows if I am exactly hovering the bar, or, if I remove the bars, exactly on the line point.

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: { display: false },
        tooltip: {
            displayColors: false, backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            bodyColor: '#595f69', bodyFont: {size: 14},
            borderColor: '#595f69', borderWidth: 1,
            titleFont: {size: 0}
        }
    },
    responsive: true, aspectRatio: 4,
    scales: {
        y: { display: true, suggestedMin: 0, suggestedMax: 80, ticks: { stepSize: 20 } },
        y1: {display: false, suggestedMin: 0, suggestedMax: 80, ticks: { stepSize: 2 }},
        x: { grid: { drawBorder: false, display: false } }
```

I tried plugins like chartjs crosshair, but don't manage to make it work with typescript.

How can I make it so that anywhere my mouse hover in the label 'column' area, the tooltip displays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `intersect` property to false to always get the tooltip without needing to intersect the bar exactly:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        intersect: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank, it works, and in addition I have added mode: 'index' and it works much better

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own tooltip by editing the callbacks, i had to get the nearest values around my cursor, from all datasets, on my line chart. this works for me on Chartjs 2.9.3:

```
tooltips: {
    mode: "x",
    position: "nearest",
    intersect: false,
    callbacks: {
        beforeBody: function(tooltipItems, allData) {
            let x = tooltipItems[0].x; // get x coordinate

            let datasets = allData.datasets; // datasets
    
            let values = [];
            for (i in datasets) {
                let dataset = datasets[i]; 

                let meta = this._chart.getDatasetMeta(i); // dataset metadata
                let xScale = this._chart.scales[meta.xAxisID]; // dataset's x axis
                let xValue = xScale.getValueForPixel(x); // we get the x value on the x axis with x coordinate

                let data = dataset.data // data

                // search data for the first value with a bigger x value
                let index = data.findIndex(function(o) { 
                    return o.x >= xValue; 
                });

                let value = data[index]; // this is our nearest value

                // format label
                if (isNaN(value.ymax)) {
                    values.push(`${dataset.label}: ${value.y}\n`);
                } else {
                    values.push(`${dataset.label}: ${value.y}, min: ${value.ymin}, max: ${value.ymax}\n`)
                }
            }

            return values.join(""); // return label
        },

        label: function() { // this needs to be empty

        },
    }
},
```